# What is the difference between These method below?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

i am learning encryption in java and used these two tutorials yet [This from Code2learn](http://www.code2learn.com/2011/06/encryption-and-decryption-of-data-using.html)

and [This from howtodoinjava.com](http://howtodoinjava.com/security/java-aes-encryption-example/)

when i try to encrypt hello from these example code both gives different encrypted strings, i have tried a lot to find that what is the main difference between these examples that is causing different encrypted strings of same passwords as both are using AES ..

Code from code 2 learn

```
package nomad;

import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import javax.crypto.*;
import sun.misc.*;

public class AESencrp {

     private static final String ALGO = "AES";
    private static final byte[] keyValue = 
        new byte[] { 'T', 'h', 'e', 'B', 'e', 's', 't',
'S', 'e', 'c', 'r','e', 't', 'K', 'e', 'y' };


public static String encrypt(String Data) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encVal = c.doFinal(Data.getBytes());
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encVal);
        return encryptedValue;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptedData) throws Exception {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGO);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedData);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return decryptedValue;
    }
    private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyValue, ALGO);
        return key;
}

}


package nomad;

public class Checker {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String password = "mypassword";
        String passwordEnc = AESencrp.encrypt(password);
        String passwordDec = AESencrp.decrypt(passwordEnc);

        System.out.println("Plain Text : " + password);
        System.out.println("Encrypted Text : " + passwordEnc);
        System.out.println("Decrypted Text : " + passwordDec);
    }
}
```

Code for how to do in java

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class AES {

    private static SecretKeySpec secretKey;
    private static byte[] key;

    public static void setKey(String myKey) 
    {
        MessageDigest sha = null;
        try {
            key = myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
            sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16); 
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
        } 
        catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToEncrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while encrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static String decrypt(String strToDecrypt, String secret) 
    {
        try
        {
            setKey(secret);
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5PADDING");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDecrypt)));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            System.out.println("Error while decrypting: " + e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    final String secretKey = "ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!";

    String originalString = "howtodoinjava.com";
    String encryptedString = AES.encrypt(originalString, secretKey) ;
    String decryptedString = AES.decrypt(encryptedString, secretKey) ;

    System.out.println(originalString);
    System.out.println(encryptedString);
    System.out.println(decryptedString);
}
```

I have added the codes as one of the comments says that external links are not accessible by everyone .

Keep in mind that secretkeys and passowrd are the same in my code.

*Adding my own code..*

**name it as code 1**

AES Class

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AES {


    public static SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;
    private static byte[] key;


    public static String setKey(String myKey) throws Exception {


        MessageDigest sha=null;

        key =myKey.getBytes("UTF-8");
        sha=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
        key=sha.digest(key);
        key= Arrays.copyOf(key,16);

        secretKeySpec=new SecretKeySpec(key,"AES");
        return myKey;
    }

    public static String encrypt(String strToencrypt, String secret) throws Exception {

        String s=  setKey(secret);
        System.out.println(s);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,secretKeySpec);
        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToencrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
    }


    public static  String decryt(String strToDec , String secret) throws Exception {
        setKey(secret);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKeySpec);
        return  new String(cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(strToDec)));
    }

}
```

Main Class of above AES Class

```
public class Main {





    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


        AES aes = new AES();

        String ss=null;
        String sd=null;
        ss=aes.encrypt("hello","TheBestSecretKey");
        sd=aes.decryt(ss,"TheBestSecretKey");

        System.out.println("The Encrypted == " + ss);
        System.out.println("The Decrypted == " + sd);



    }


}
```

*Another Code*

**Name It as Code 2**

```
package sample;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;

import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.Key;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main  {


    private static final String ALGO ="AES";
    private static String string  = "TheBestSecretKey";
    private static  byte[] key ;
    private static SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;



    public static String  aesEncrypt(String en) throws Exception {

        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(string.getBytes(),ALGO);
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,key);
        byte[] encValue =c.doFinal(en.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String encryptedValue= new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
return encryptedValue;

    }

    public static String aesDecrypt(String De) throws Exception{

        Key key = new SecretKeySpec(string.getBytes(),"AES");

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,key);
       // return  new String(c.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(De)));

        byte[]decodedVlue=new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(De);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decodedVlue);
        String deccryptedValue = new String(decValue);
        return deccryptedValue;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String password = "hello";
        String passEnc= Main.aesEncrypt(password);
        System.out.println(passEnc);
        String passDec = Main.aesDecrypt(passEnc);
        System.out.println(passDec);

    }
}
```

here are the codes
now i am also posting encrypted strings

using SecretSpecKey TheBestSecretKey and hello as the string to be encrypted

**CODE 1  UlQiIs/K0EwcSKbWMjcT1g==**

**CODE 2  hHDBo1dJYj5RcjdFA6BBfw==**

Comment: Please post the relevant code here instead of hiding it behind links. And try to make your question more specific.... "Please help me" is too vague.

Comment: Have you made sure you use the same secret key with both?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your problem. External links are not always reachable for everyone (including me)

Comment: So I have added the codes please check

Comment: Sorry @RobinTopper for using that please .... but guidelines doesn't included that .

Comment: They're not both using the same "password", whether you meant the secret key, or the contents to encrypt.  The top code uses "TheBestSecretKey" to encrypt "mypassword"; the bottom code uses "ssshhhhhhhhhhh!!!!" to encrypt "howtodoinjava.com".  So, they produce different answers because they have different inputs.

Comment: yes @Mark mark i have same secretkeys and password,

Comment: no @user55924 like bartonjs already said, you do not.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion . initially i didn't posted the code, it was asked to do so i simply copied the codes from their respective sites and pasted here , as i already told in last line of my question that in my case i have same keys and passwords ..
@Mark

Comment: Yes. "codes". But it's far from a minimal, complete and verifiable example and it doesn't even appear to be YOUR code, seeing as you just commented on how in your code things are different. How are we supposed to help you figure this out if you don't post your own code? And in a way that we can test it to reproduce the error?

Comment: @Mark thanks for your reply please take a look now i posted my code!
ThankYou

Comment: @AxelH please review my question i  updated it

Comment: Alright. The difference between the two is the way you convert your secret key into a byte array. It's done manually in `setKey` in your first algorithm and your second algorithm simply uses `String.getBytes()`. But the way it's done manually is simply different than the way it's done in the `getBytes()` method. So you get different byte arrays, which result in different encryptions.